# F#: Using a F# indexed property from C#

Tags: f#

I have written a class in F# implementing an interface in order to build a C#-friendly interface for my F#-assembly.

I have written some of the properties as indexed properties. However, when I try to use the type from C#, I only get the synthetic get_PropertyName methods in intellisense and the compiler likewise complains in case I want to use the indexed properties like I would do for C# ones.

Code for reference:

```
type IMyInterfaceType =   
    abstract MyProperty : MyType1 with get
    abstract MyIndexedProperty : MyType2 -> MyType3 with get
    abstract MyTwoDimensionalIndexedProperty : (MyType4 * MyType5) -> MyType6 with get

type MyInterfaceType =   

    new () = { }

    interface IMyInterfaceType with
        member this.MyProperty with get () = new MyType1 ()
        member this.MyIndexedProperty with get parameter = new MyType3 ()
        member this.MyTwoDimensionalIndexedProperty with get pair = new MyType6 ()
```

When trying to access this class from C#, I only get methods

```
get_MyIndexedProperty(MyType2 parameter)
get_MyTwoDimensionalIndexedProperty(Tuple<MyType4, MyType5>)
```

instead of the indexed properties I had hoped for.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue?

cheers
--Mathias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Response to the original question**:

Indexer properties in C# have special name `Item` thus to create indexer accessible from C# you must name your indexer property "Item", e.g.:

```
type X () =
    member this.Item with get key = ....
```

Now it can be accessed both in F# using `(x : X).[key]` or in C# using x[key] .

**Response to the updated question**:

C# does not support indexed properties the way F# does. Instead using additional type is advised: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

So you can try to use something like this:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Indexer<'index, 'result> () =
    abstract Get : 'index -> 'result
    member this.Item with get key = this.Get key

type IMyInterfaceType =   
    abstract MyProperty : MyType1 with get
    // F# indexed propetties
    abstract MyIndexedProperty : MyType2 -> MyType3 with get
    // C# workaround
    abstract MyCSharpIndexedProperty : Indexer<MyType2, MyType3> with get

type MyInterfaceType () as this =
    let proxy =
      { new Indexer<MyType2, MyType3> () with
          member __.Get key = (this :> IMyInterfaceType).MyIndexedProperty key }
    interface IMyInterfaceType with
        member __.MyProperty with get () = new MyType1 ()
        member __.MyIndexedProperty with get key = new MyType3 ()
        member __.MyCSharpIndexedProperty with get () = proxy
```

And two dimensional property similarly by creating `Indexer<'index1, 'index2, 'result> () = ...`

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Calls like object.Property[key] work in C# because the Type of the property has an indexer instead of the capability for indexing the property lying in the class of the property. Thanks for the clarification!